# How to run a particular .java class from Android project (Android Studio 2.2)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to find the "run the class" option in Android Studio 2.2. How can I run just a particular class (for test purposes) withour launching the whole application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a main method to the class to run it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this code will be run
}
```

In there you can instantiate an instance of your class.

The typical and robust way to assert behaviour would be to write unit tests instead.

Comment: Really THANKS. May I add some Tags, java android studio console pure class

Comment: So what "Run/Debug Configuration" should we make to run the class?

Answer (score 2):

If you write instrumentation tests or unit tests, you will have icons in the gutter (gray bar to the side of the source code in the editor) to run an individual test method or all test methods in the class. However, outside of that, there is no concept of "run just a particular class" in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Directly right click on the .java file you will get drop down in that click on run option with that .java file name.
Example: MainActivity.java is your file, right click on this file and click on run'MainActivity'.